# React app is not installing using terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

Tried so many times installing react app using terminal but always shows node is not recognised as internal batch file.
although node --version gives me v12.8.3

[image]

Comment: Hello, please include what terminal you are running in, and what command/script you are running. Please also include any error messages you are seeing as plain text. We generally just need more details about what you are trying to do. If it's a script from a package.json file please include as much of that as possible.

Comment: See,I have attached the screenshot.I am using hyper terminal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: It Sounds like Node didn't properly get added to your PATH 
I also use Hyper there might be a pathing issue in the configurations/settings for Hyper as well
This article might be able to help:
https://love2dev.com/blog/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: What is your operating system and how did you install Node?

Comment: OS is windows and I installed node from its website.

Comment: Also I have worked with nodejs while studying backend but during react I dont know why it is coming like this

Comment: Do you have node installed for the Windows Console, or the Linux subsystem? It may sound silly, but have you tried running your terminal as Admin?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: From ***that*** terminal, what is the result of `node -v`? And about running the terminal as admin, it's a silly windows thing, but sometime you need to run the console/terminal as Admin to run/install certain things in certain directories. Googling how to do this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer.
Just tried windows command prompt rather than the hyper terminal I was using,and react app got installed.

Comment: you can close this question now.